# Hide multi select option set field in Dyanmics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a multiselect option set field in dynamcis 365 and I want to hide it based on the value of another field....my problem is that setVisible function is not available for this type of field.

Is there any way I could handle it with javascript? What should I do?

Comment: You can write a simple business rule. When other field has value you can set visibility false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setVisible()` is available for both single and multi-select option set controls.

Ensure you are calling `setVisible()` on the multi-select control, **not** the attribute:

```
if (valueOfOtherFieldIsX) {
  formContex.getControl("prefix_multiSelectLogicalName").setVisible(false);
}
```